# How to keep multiple image in a single row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**I am trying to keep some image in a single row**. I am using bootstrap and image also including responsive class.

After 12 image new row has create for the rest of the image. **But I want  all image keep in a single row.**

I have my code in this format

```
<ul class="people">
    <li><a><img ></a>
    <li><a><img ></a>
</ul>
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to keep using `li`?

Comment: yes actually i want to keep all li in a single row.

Comment: .people li{width:100px;display:inline-block; float:left; margin:0 10px;}

Comment: @sujanmridha My answer does exactly what you asked for. Is there something I misinterpreted?

Answer (score 2):

> After 12 image new row has create for the rest of the image. But I
>   want all image keep in a single row.

These images stays in a single row no matter how many.

```css
.people li {
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<ul class="people">
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" ></a>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" ></a>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" ></a>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" ></a>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" ></a>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" ></a>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" ></a>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" ></a>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" ></a>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" ></a>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" ></a>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" ></a>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" ></a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way in twitter-bootstrap is the class `row` whit div

```
   <div  class="row">

       <div><a><img src='your_img_1' ></a></div>
       <div><a><img src='your_img_2'></a></div>
       <div><a><img src='your_img_3'></a></div>
   </div>
```

Or If you need the image in  `<ul class="list-inline">`  you need an inline block style 
or for img

```
img {
  border: 0 none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/68Pzyk8g2obhBYrxPLzA?p=preview).

HTML code:

```
<ul class="people">
  <li>
    <a><img src="http://blue-engineering.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Slider-blue.png"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/Red_flag.svg/2000px-Red_flag.svg.png"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS code:

```
img{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Hope this is what you asked for :)

Comment: but I must not to use fixed widht and height

Comment: @sujanmridha if you give the image only a width or height, it will stay in the original scale.
And the only reason I gave it a width and height was because the picture were huge.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use **display** or **float** code for this.

Example:

```
li{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

OR

```
li{
  float:left;
}
```

But its better to use display code. because if you want to use float code, then you need to add a clear code after finish floating..

Example:

```
<ul class="people">
    <li><a><img ></a>
    <li><a><img ></a>
</ul>
<div class="people2">
your stuff... here
 </div>
```

CSS

```
li{
  float:left;
}
.people2 {
  clear:both
}
```

So... I think its better to use **display:inline-block**

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
    li
    {
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

After 12 image new row has create for the rest of the image

```
    li:nth-child(12n)
    {
    clear:both;
    }
```